Ideal diode in parallel with resistor and voltage source
Sorry if this appears to be a silly question, but it is a concept I am having trouble with.

I don't quite get how to arrive at this plot. The current from V1 as a function of V1.
If V1 > 0 then I know that the diode is on, making a short circuit.
The current in the other branch is (V1-1)/R1 but what is the current in the short circuit branch?
Secondly, if V1 < 0, the diode is off so shouldn't the total current be (V1-1)/R1 and not 0?

If I told you that LTspice incorporates a 1 milli ohm resistor inside a voltage source by default, would that make it easier for you to understand? I mean, have you considered that with the tools to hand, you could simply short out V1 and get the same graph when V1 is positive?
Have you also considered that the ampere scale of you graph (kA not A or mA) is so big that what looks like zero amps is not quite zero amps. Hint: the value of R1 is 1 kΩ so, how will you effectively see 1 mA on your graph when V1 is zero?

Ok, I set Rser = 0 for the voltage sources.
And fixed the scale by zooming in and letting R1 = 1m ohm, and indeed as you said there is current! Thanks.
But I still don't get V1 > 0, how to determine the current in the shorted branch? (Infinity? (theoretically))

You can't hope to determine the current numerically if the series resistance is zero because the voltage is forced to be zero (even when it apparently isn't) and, you have a non-real-world scenario that involves infinity.

Ok I think I got it, thank you a lot!

For completeness, the 1milliohm resistance is not from the voltage sources (default value is indeed zero for those).  It's from the PWL diode .model statement.  Setting Ron to zero is invalid so LTspice rejects it and uses the default value of 1milliohm for that parameter.  Unfortunately, it doesn't notify you it automatically does this...not even in the Error Log where you typically see adjustments like this.

Have you looked at the scale of current measurement?
If the supply and diode were ideal, the current would be infinite or actually it might fail to simulate because two nodes combined with 0 ohms must have equal voltage and you can't have 0V over a 2V supply or 2V over an ideal diode.
The scale is 2000 amps at 2V so somewhere in there you have a 1 milliohm resistance or the current would be infinite and with that scale you cannot see the mA scale current through the 1kohm resistor.

Yeah just fixed the scale; sorry.
But for V1 > 0 shouldn't the current be infinity?
Yeah that is what is confusing me, the node at the top is "V1" but if the branch is shorted then V1 = gnd = 0??

@Nero But I just explained you have 1 milliohm defined somewhere, otherwise you do get infinities or rather the software complaining it is not possible to have both a voltage drop and no voltage drop at the same time.

Yep thanks. Sorry for my stupidity, after a minute of posting the comment I realized it..

@Nero  Heads up that your 1milliohm is coming from setting Ron=0 for the diode .model statement.  LTspice rejects that value (it's invalid) and uses the default of 1 milliohm.  Regardless, it's never a good idea to set resistance parameters to pure zero in a simulator.


I still don't get V1 > 0, how to determine the current in the shorted branch

You actually can't because the schematic you have is not a schematic of any real circuit. It is a graphical representation of a connection matrix used in circuit analysis. In circuit analysis, having a voltage source shorted is not allowed and there's no way to analyze such a circuit. There are no infinities. The configuration with V1>0 is simply meaningless and not a valid input for the analysis. Some SPICEs detect it, some work around by adding hidden resistances, leading to somewhat confusing results.
A proper SPICE (with a symbolic preprocessor) would stop the plot at V1=0. There is no plot for V1>0. Whatever SPICE has plotted in that region is bogus.
